# There's a bug in CNContactPickerController

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact, cncontactviewcontroller

After spending all day (>12 hours) trying to isolate a bug in 13 lines of mind-bogglingly generic code, I have come to the dubious conclusion that there must be a bug in the current iteration of `CNContactPickerViewController`, in iOS 9.2.

Simply copy+paste this `ViewController` and link the `invite` action to a button.

The bug is that `MFMessageComposeViewController` dismisses itself immediately.

If anybody knows what to do with this, do share?

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI
import ContactsUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate, CNContactPickerDelegate {

    let contactPickerVC = CNContactPickerViewController()
    let messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        contactPickerVC.delegate = self
    }

    func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContact contact: CNContact) {
        if let phoneNumberValue = contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value as? CNPhoneNumber {
            if let phoneNumber = phoneNumberValue.valueForKey("digits") as? String {

                // Configure message ViewController
                messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self
                messageVC.recipients = [phoneNumber]
                messageVC.body = "Yoyoyo"
                picker.presentViewController(messageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        }
    }

    func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {
       controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func invite(sender: AnyObject) {
        presentViewController(contactPickerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you file a radar yet?

Comment: Simulator or device?  Because this code will work only on a device capable of text messaging and that leaves out the simulator.

Comment: Please add what exactly is going wrong and the error to the question. Also, report bugs in iOS to Apple: https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: @GlennRay Device! try it out in a new project, will literally take you 30 secs...

Comment: @Cristik Check it out, edited

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @matt Sorry I forgot the question mark

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by dismissing the pickerVC and changing the controller which presents the messageVC!

Insert (before the messageVC config lines):

```
 picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Replace

```
picker.presentViewController(messageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

with

```
  presentViewController(messageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```